# Unhandled Rejection (InvalidCharacterError): Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded

Tags: reactjs, axios, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Here in my Django React app, I'm trying to sign in but encounter this error:
[image]

On similar posts regarding the issue, I was suggested to add decodeUriComponent, but still did not work.

Below is the code section for axios.js that got the issue:

```js
if (refreshToken) {
                console.log('My refresh_token = ' + refreshToken.split('.')[1])
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(refreshToken.split('.')[1])));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);
```

It's strange how it worked the last time I compiled. Maybe I ran into some Node version-related conflicts. Could you show me a way to solve this?

***UPDATE***
My refresh token is also undefined. I tried posting a POST request to /api/users/login and got the cookies!

[image]

My axios.js code:

**axios.py**

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('access_token') ? "JWT " + localStorage.getItem('access_token') : null,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
});


axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                    'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                    'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'token/refresh/'
        ) {
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'token_not_valid' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                console.log('My refresh_token = ' + refreshToken.split('.')[1])
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(decodeURIComponent(refreshToken.split('.')[1])));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'JWT ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Comment: Share all code from `axios.js`

Comment: @VitaliyRayets Yes I have updated my axios.js as per your request. Could you have a look?

Comment: You have invalid `refresh_token` string in localStorage like 'undefined'. Clear `refresh_token`   in localStorage to start. F12->Application->Local Storage->Your domain->refresh_token

Comment: `atob('undefined')`  will throw `Uncaught DOMException`, you can find why your `response.data.refresh` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion. I bypassed the first issue but when i tried to console.log response.data.refresh it just said 'undefined' :(

Comment: Yup, `response.data` haven't property `refresh`, it's your issue

Comment: Thank you for you help. I changed from response.data.refresh to localStorage.getItem('refreshToken') but still undefined.

Comment: You miss refresh token from server, it's not problem with client

Comment: @VitaliyRayets I'll check my Django backend then